# Insert values into a JSON object using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to write a script which allows one to define form field and write a JSON schema based off that.

```
{
   "createContact":{
      "method":"POST",
      "sobject":"Contact",
      "Intangible\/Event.payload":{
         "FirstName":"contact_first_name",
         "LastName":"contact_last_name",
         "MobilePhone":"contact_phone",
         "HomePhone":"contact_phone",
         "npe01__PreferredPhone__c":"Mobile",
         "MailingStreet":"address_unit_no",
         "MailingCity":"address_suburb",
         "MailingState":"address_state",
         "MailingPostalCode":"address_postcode",
         "MailingCountry":"address_country",
         "npe01__HomeEmail__c":"contact_email",
         "npe01__Preferred_Email__c":"Personal",
         "Stripe_Customer_ID__c":"stripe_customer_id"
      }
   },
   "createOpportunity":{
      "method":"POST",
      "sobject":"Opportunity",
      "Intangible\/Event.payload":{
         "StageName":"stage_name",
         "Type":"donation_type",
         "Amount":"donation_amount",
         "PD_Payment_Method__c":"Web",
         "CampaignId":"campaign_id",
         "RecordTypeId":"record_id",
         "Name":"opportunity_name",
         "CloseDate":"date",
         "Description":"description",
         "Stripe_Card_ID__c":"stripe_card",
      }
   }
}
```

I have setup dummy values and I want to replace those values from the form inputs. There are also certain fields such as Stripe_Customer_ID__c etc. which need to be populated from Stripe after a successful transaction.

I have tried to convert the JSON object to a PHP object and then populate the values using foreach loops however due to certain fields not been part of the form it has proved a bit challenging. I want to be able to reuse the code so that if the user changes the schema and form fields the code will still pick it up and add in the correct values.

For instance if `Stripe_Card_ID__c` changed to `Stripe_Card__c` I would like the code to pick that up and assign the correct value.

I would like to know if there is an easier way to handle mapping without the use of foreach loops for uncertain data.

The code I have currently written

```
foreach($mapping as $mapping_key => $mapping_event){
            if(is_object($mapping_event)){
                foreach($mapping_event as $key => $value){
                    if(is_object($value)){
                        foreach($value as $inner_key => $inner_value){ 
                            if(isset($data[$inner_value])){
                                $event[$mapping_key][$key][$inner_key] = (string)$data[$inner_value];
                            }else{
                                $event[$mapping_key][$key][$inner_key] = $inner_value;
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        $event[$mapping_key][$key] = $value;

                        if($value == 'query'){
                            $event[$mapping_key][$key] = "";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $event[$mapping_key] = $mapping_event;
            }
        }
```

This does output certain field which it picked up from the form however the more unique fields for each Salesforce account is the hard bit.

```
array(4) {
  ["createContact"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["method"]=>
    string(4) "POST"
    ["sobject"]=>
    string(7) "Contact"
    ["Intangible/Event.payload"]=>
    array(13) {
      ["FirstName"]=>
      string(3) "asd"
      ["LastName"]=>
      string(3) "asd"
      ["MobilePhone"]=>
      string(13) "contact_phone"
      ["HomePhone"]=>
      string(13) "contact_phone"
      ["npe01__PreferredPhone__c"]=>
      string(6) "Mobile"
      ["MailingStreet"]=>
      string(36) "address_unit_no"
      ["MailingCity"]=>
      string(3) "asd"
      ["MailingState"]=>
      string(3) "asd"
      ["MailingPostalCode"]=>
      string(3) "asd"
      ["MailingCountry"]=>
      string(2) "AF"
      ["npe01__HomeEmail__c"]=>
      string(11) "asd@asd.asd"
      ["npe01__Preferred_Email__c"]=>
      string(8) "Personal"
      ["Stripe_Customer_ID__c"]=>
      string(18) "stripe_customer_id"
    }
  }
  ["createOpportunity"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["method"]=>
    string(4) "POST"
    ["sobject"]=>
    string(11) "Opportunity"
    ["Intangible/Event.payload"]=>
    array(13) {
      ["StageName"]=>
      string(10) "stage_name"
      ["Type"]=>
      string(4) "once"
      ["Amount"]=>
      string(2) "52"
      ["PD_Payment_Method__c"]=>
      string(3) "Web"
      ["CampaignId"]=>
      string(11) "campaign_id"
      ["RecordTypeId"]=>
      string(9) "record_id"
      ["Name"]=>
      string(16) "opportunity_name"
      ["CloseDate"]=>
      string(4) "date"
      ["Description"]=>
      string(11) "description"
      ["Platform_Donation_ID__c "]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["Stripe_Card_ID__c"]=>
      string(11) "stripe_card"
      ["Stripe_Fingerprint__c "]=>
      string(18) "stripe_fingerprint"
      ["Conga_Trigger__c"]=>
      string(13) "conga_trigger"
    }
  }
......
}
```

As you can see the above result only has certain fields that have been substituted.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up managing each array individually. Given the difference of the fields I found this easier. Certain fields I had to hard code which I will look probably look at another time but got the initial draft working which is good news.